# Understanding Domain Error in MATLAB: Causes and Solutions

Tags: matlab

When converting a MATLAB code to a MEX file, I encountered a domain error related to complex numbers. The error message reads: "Domain error. To compute complex results from real x, use 'sqrt(complex(x))'." The error stemmed from the following line of code:

```matlab
g = 2*exp(-sqrt(-1)*k*r)/(4*pi*r);
```

When I changed the code to the following:

```matlab
g = 2*exp(-sqrt(complex(-1))*k*r)/(4*pi*r);
```

I encountered a new error in the next line:

```
Ge = Ge+Ne1*g*w1(ii,jj)*w2(ii,jj)*je;
```

The new error message reads: "Cannot assign a complex value into a non-complex location." Both lines of code define "g," but I do not understand why the second line throws an error.

Comment: You probably declared `Ge` as `double`, but it's a complex value, so needs to be declared as complex. But I cannot be sure, because you're not giving enough information. I suggest you read [mre], then [edit] your question to complete it. It is really hard to understand a problem without having all the relevant details.

Comment: g = 2*exp(-sqrt(-1)*k*r)/(4*pi*r);
%g = 2*exp(-sqrt(complex(-1))*k*r)/(4*pi*r);
            
  Ge = Ge+Ne1*g*w1(ii,jj)*w2(ii,jj)*je;
in this case error is shown : Domain error. To compute complex results from real x, use 'sqrt(complex(x))'.  error is shown here : g = 2*exp(-sqrt(-1)*k*r)/(4*pi*r);

%g = 2*exp(-sqrt(-1)*k*r)/(4*pi*r);
 g = 2*exp(-sqrt(complex(-1))*k*r)/(4*pi*r);
            
  Ge = Ge+Ne1*g*w1(ii,jj)*w2(ii,jj)*je;   
in this case error is shown : Cannot assign a complex value into a non-complex location. error is shown here : Ge = Ge+Ne1*g*w1(ii,jj)*w2(ii,jj)*je;

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the code. Code in a comment is useless, it cannot be read. But make sure it is complete, minimal code, not just a couple of lines. As described in [mre]. I have given you both links before. Please use them.